# How to divide the column into several columns in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like this:

| ACT_DAY | user | OFFER_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9/8/2023 | 111 | offer_1 |
| 7/1/2023 | 111 | offer_2 |
| 7/21/2023 | 111 | Offer_3 |
| 6/15/2023 | 111 | offer_1 |

and I want table like this:

| user | ACT_DAY | OFFER_NAME | ACT_DAY | OFFER_NAME | ACT_DAY | OFFER_NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 6/15/2023 | offer_1 | 7/1/2023 | offer_2 | 7/21/2023 | Offer_3 | offer_1 |

My code is this:

```
select user_id,
      Substr (offer_names, 1 , instr (offer_names, ',') - 1) as offer_name,
      Substr (act_dates, 1 , instr (act_dates, ',') - 1) as act_date,
      substr (offer_names, instr ( offer_names, ',') + 1) as next_offer_name,
      substr (act_dates, instr ( act_dates, ',') + 1) as next_act_date
from
(select u.user_id,,
       regexp_replace(listagg(o.offer_name, ',') within GROUP(ORDER BY o.day desc), '([^,]*)(,\1)+($|,)', '\1\3') as offer_names,
       regexp_replace(listagg(o.day, ',') within GROUP(ORDER BY o.day desc), '([^,]*)(,\1)+($|,)', '\1\3') as act_dates
   from user u
left join offer o on u.offer_id=o.id
    where user = '111'
group by user)
```

but it doesn't work due to it split only firs value.
What is it other option?

Comment: Search for the term "sql pivot" and you'll find plenty of examples.

Comment: In this particular case, pivot will not work.,because I don't need to aggregate_function and  have 2 values.Did you see my table?

Comment: You typically shouldn't project a result set which has duplicate column names. How is an application supposed to know which `act_day` pairs with which `offer_name`?

Comment: Do you have a limit on the number of act_days a user will have? If not, this feels like an XY problem. I don't figure there are many cases where dynamically pivoting into an arbitrary number of grouped pairs is the best approach. That's neither going to be easy for a human or machine to read.

Comment: I'm not very good with Oracle, but [here's a solution](https://dbfiddle.uk/8vQF9v_k) that uses SQL Server. You should be able to adapt this to your use case. You need to have some identifer (in my case, I just used an auto incrementing `RID` column) to know which `act_day` pairs with which `offer_name`. Note, this is a _static_ solution that assumes a fixed number of rows you are aggregating, which is probably not realistic. You may need to make this dynamic (like @Error_2646 mentioned).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number the rows using the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function and then `PIVOT` based on the row numbers:

```sql
SELECT "user",
       "1_ACT_DAY" AS act_day1,
       "1_OFFER_NAME" AS offer_name1,
       "2_ACT_DAY" AS act_day2,
       "2_OFFER_NAME" AS offer_name2,
       "3_ACT_DAY" AS act_day3,
       "3_OFFER_NAME" AS offer_name3,
       "4_ACT_DAY" AS act_day4,
       "4_OFFER_NAME" AS offer_name4
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY "user" ORDER BY act_day
         ) AS rn
  FROM   table_name t
)
PIVOT (
  MAX(act_day) AS act_day,
  MAX(offer_name) AS offer_name
  FOR rn IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ACT_DAY, "user", OFFER_NAME) AS
SELECT DATE '2023-09-08', 111, 'offer_1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-07-01', 111, 'offer_2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-07-21', 111, 'offer_3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2023-06-15', 111, 'offer_1' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| user | ACT_DAY1 | OFFER_NAME1 | ACT_DAY2 | OFFER_NAME2 | ACT_DAY3 | OFFER_NAME3 | ACT_DAY4 | OFFER_NAME4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 2023-06-15 00:00:00 | offer_1 | 2023-07-01 00:00:00 | offer_2 | 2023-07-21 00:00:00 | offer_3 | 2023-09-08 00:00:00 | offer_1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kVObBQJ9)

Answer (score 1):

You could use MODEL clause, Just create enough measure pairs, define rules for them and put them in selection list of outer query.

```sql
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl (ACT_DAY, USER_ID, OFFER_NAME) as
        ( Select DATE '2023-09-08', 111, 'offer_1' From Dual Union All
          Select DATE '2023-07-01', 111, 'offer_2' From Dual Union All
          Select DATE '2023-07-21', 111, 'offer_3' From Dual Union All
          Select DATE '2023-06-15', 111, 'offer_1' From Dual 
        )
```

```sql
--    M a i n    S Q L :
SELECT  USER_ID, 
        ACT_DAY_1, OFFER_NAME_1, -- columns defined in Measures and         
        ACT_DAY_2, OFFER_NAME_2, -- populated with values in RULES
        ACT_DAY_3, OFFER_NAME_3, -- you can create more of them
        ACT_DAY_4, OFFER_NAME_4  -- if needed
FROM   ( Select     *
          From  ( Select ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition By USER_ID Order By ACT_DAY) "RN", ACT_DAY, USER_ID, OFFER_NAME
                  From   tbl    --  Row Number used in RULES to address values one after another
                )
              MODEL Partition By ( USER_ID )
                    Dimension By ( RN )
                  Measures  ( ACT_DAY, OFFER_NAME, 
                              Cast(Null as DATE) ACT_DAY_1, Cast(Null as VarChar2(16)) "OFFER_NAME_1", 
                              Cast(Null as DATE) ACT_DAY_2, Cast(Null as VarChar2(16)) "OFFER_NAME_2", 
                              Cast(Null as DATE) ACT_DAY_3, Cast(Null as VarChar2(16)) "OFFER_NAME_3", 
                              Cast(Null as DATE) ACT_DAY_4, Cast(Null as VarChar2(16)) "OFFER_NAME_4"
                            )
              RULES ( ACT_DAY_1[0] = ACT_DAY[1], 
                      OFFER_NAME_1[0] = OFFER_NAME[1], 
                      ACT_DAY_2[0] = ACT_DAY[2], 
                      OFFER_NAME_2[0] = OFFER_NAME[2], 
                      ACT_DAY_3[0] = ACT_DAY[3], 
                      OFFER_NAME_3[0] = OFFER_NAME[3],
                      ACT_DAY_4[0] = ACT_DAY[4], 
                      OFFER_NAME_4[0] = OFFER_NAME[4]
                    )
        )
WHERE RN = 0  -- RowNum [0] created as a separate row with all the values collected
```

```sql
/*      R e s u l t :
   USER_ID ACT_DAY_ OFFER_NAME_1     ACT_DAY_ OFFER_NAME_2     ACT_DAY_ OFFER_NAME_3     ACT_DAY_ OFFER_NAME_4    
---------- -------- ---------------- -------- ---------------- -------- ---------------- -------- ----------------
       111 15.06.23 offer_1          01.07.23 offer_2          21.07.23 offer_3          08.09.23 offer_1           */
```

More about MODEL clause at: [enter link description here](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/10g/r2/prod/bidw/sqlmodel/sqlmodel_otn.htm)